# Kali linux can not detect my embedded wifi card

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, kali-linux, wifi-driver

I installed *Kali Linux* on my laptop but I can not use my wifi card. My laptop is **HP Pavilion Gaming Laptop 15-ec2000nv** and my embedded wifi card is **Intel® Wi-Fi 6 AX200**. I found the drivers for the specific wifi model but I could not complete the process because it does not include any *make* file.

https://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/uk/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the wireless driver for **Intel® Wi-Fi 6 AX200**
2. Extract `tar xzf iwlwifi-*.tgz`
3. Copy the firmware `sudo cp iwlwifi-* /lib/firmware`
4. Reboot

Comment: Just did that and still nothing. Any other idea?

Comment: What kernel version are you on? Also please post dmesg logs

Comment: Linux 5.11.0-27-generic